# Element wise divide like MATLAB's ./ operator?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to normalize some Nx3 data. If X is a Nx3 array and D is a Nx1 array, in MATLAB, I can do
Y = X./D

If I do the following in Python, I get an error

```
X = np.random.randn(100,3)    
D = np.linalg.norm(X,axis=1)
Y = X/D

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,3) (100,)
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: Thanks to dm2.

```
Y = X/D.reshape((100,1))
```

Another way is to use scikitlearn.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
Y = preprocessing.normalize(X)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:%7E:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how,that%20they%20have%20compatible%20shapes.&text=NumPy%20operations%20are%20usually%20done,element%2Dby%2Delement%20basis.) on array broadcasting:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
> element-wise. It starts with the trailing (i.e. rightmost) dimensions
> and works its way left. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

Both of your arrays have the same first dimension, but your X array is 2-dimensional, while your D array is 1-dimensional, which means the shapes of these two arrays do not meet the requirements to be broadcast together.

To make sure they do, you could reshape your D array into a 2-dimensional array of shape (100,1), which would satisfy the requirements to broadcast: rightmost dimensions are 3 and 1 (one of them is 1) and the other dimensions are equal (100 and 100).

So:

```
Y = X/D.reshape((-1,1))
```

or

```
Y = X/D.reshape((100,1))
```

or

```
Y = X/D[:,np.newaxis]
```

Should give you the result you're after.